# property'auth' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuthModule' error

Tags: angular, authentication

It does not recognize **auth** despite I already put **AngularFireAuthModule** in `app.module`.

putting **AngularFireAuthModule** in `app.module:

```java
 this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition you need to add `import ...` and declare your imported library in `constructor`:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export class FooYourClass {

    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

    login() {    
        this.afAuth.auth
            .signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
    }
}
```

Comment: @AzkuIzad could you post the full code? It is hard to figure out without your code.

Comment: @AzkuIzad glad to hear that you've solved your problem!:)

Comment: hey man it works what I did was reinstall back the angular/fire and put only 'import at my {angularFireAuth } ' at top of my login.compponent.ts  . I did not put import { AngularFireAuth } from in my app.module.ts because somehow it made my page goes blank when I run ng serve,does this my action safe ? sorry I try to upload my code at comment but it said got some error ,I am pretty new here .

Comment: @AzkuIzad it is better to write like it is written above to avoid errors. You cannot upload your code here, you can just write relevant code into your question.